Cmake find_package() doesn't find library
I've just started using cmake on a Jetson Embedded Linux (it's based on Ubuntu 18.04). I have downloaded and installed this library separately and can see it has copied its .cmake files in the relevant folder:
ls /usr/local/lib/cmake/
NemaTodeConfig.cmake  NemaTodeConfig-noconfig.cmake  NemaTodeVersion.cmake

When I run
cmake --debug-find .

, what puzzles me is that it seems to almost avoid the files for my library and obviously report that it couldn't find it:
> cmake --debug-find .
> Checking prefix [/usr/local/]
> Checking file [/usr/local/NemaTodeConfig.cmake]
> Checking file [/usr/local/nematode-config.cmake]
> Checking file [/usr/local/lib/cmake/NemaTodeVersion.cmake/NemaTodeConfig.cmake]
> Checking file [/usr/local/lib/cmake/NemaTodeVersion.cmake/nematode-config.cmake]
> Checking file [/usr/local/lib/cmake/NemaTodeConfig-noconfig.cmake/NemaTodeConfig.cmake]
> Checking file [/usr/local/lib/cmake/NemaTodeConfig-noconfig.cmake/nematode-config.cmake]
> Checking file [/usr/local/lib/cmake/NemaTodeConfig.cmake/NemaTodeConfig.cmake]
> Checking file [/usr/local/lib/cmake/NemaTodeConfig.cmake/nematode-config.cmake]

LE: I managed to get it to work by adding set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH  ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "/usr/local/lib/cmake") before the find_package() command, but still find it odd how it would simply seem to avoid it by default.

/usr/local/lib/cmake/NemaTodeVersion.cmake/NemaTodeConfig.cmake - this path combines names of two files (NemaTodeVersion.cmake and NemaTodeConfig.cmake). This is not how CMake normally searches config files. How exactly you call find_package?

Like this: find_package(NemaTode CONFIG)
